# Getting a model is undefined error after upgrading to Ember 3.20.2

Tags: ember.js

We have upgraded a few projects to use Ember 3.20.2 and we are working through issues and it's mostly going fine, but I have a really strange issue in one project.

We have retrieved records from the server as models, these models then get passed down a few levels through components and all the information about the model can be displayed in these components, except when we try and render one particular field on a template. The problem part of the template looks like:

```
<div title={{task.details.title}}>
    {{task.details.title}}
</div>
```

and the model has the following:

```
details: DS.attr(),
```

The error that appears in the console looks like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: task is undefined
    Ember 2
        taskHelper
        fnWrapper
    deprecateMutationsInAutotrackingTransaction validator.js:149
    fnWrapper Ember
    computeTag reference.js:250
    runInAutotrackingTransaction validator.js:121
    track validator.js:774
    compute reference.js:249
    HelperRootReference reference.js:223
    Ember 2
        EmberHelperRootReference
        _lookupHelper
    ...
```

Is details now a restricted word? Some other issue?

Edit:

Actually I think I have narrowed down what the error is. It doesn't seem to like the title being {{task.details.title}}. If I remove the title attribute everything seems to be working fine. The documentation for deprecateMutationsInAutotrackingTransaction is:

```
/**
     * Switches to deprecating within an autotracking transaction, if one exists.
     * If `runInAutotrackingTransaction` is called within the callback of this
     * method, it switches back to throwing an error, allowing zebra-striping of
     * the types of errors that are thrown.
     *
     * Does not start an autotracking transaction.
     *
     * NOTE: For Ember usage only, in general you should assert that these
     * invariants are true.
     */
```

which may suggest why some title attributes are failing, but I cannot make out much from that documentation.

Comment: I'm confused to see `taskHelper` and `fnHelper` in the stack trace. Are you sure that the template you have posted is causing the error? It doesn't use either of these helpers. Ember Concurrency [provides](https://github.com/machty/ember-concurrency/blob/master/addon/helpers/task.js) a template helper called `taskHelper`, which uses a `task` variable. Calling that helper with `undefined` as first positional argument (or without any) would explain the error way better than the template snippet included in the question does.

Comment: That particular part of the template is what seems to be causing the issue, as I mention in my edit it seems to be related to the title attribute. If I change the title attribute to be ```title={{detailsTitle}}``` and have a computed property in the component.js file that just returns task.details.title it works fine, however, putting the computed property in the model itself doesn't work and I get the same error, so I have a workaround. Is there a problem with the model being called task?

Comment: I am not ruling out something else in our code is contributing to the issue, but only seems to manifest itself in this one particular place.

Comment: I should have said - we are not using the taskHelper function anywhere in our code, but it may be used in a dependency.

Comment: From where does the `task` definition come from? Is it a template only component, a glimmer component or an ember component? Should it be `@task` or `this.task` instead? Can you confirm `{{task.id}}` at the exactly same place works?